# Express $P$ as a function of $H$ for quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, parity

Let $H = \frac{1}{2}(p^2+x^2) $ and $P$ is the inversion or parity operator, $P\psi(x) = \psi(-x)$.
I have already proven that $P$ is unitary and Hermitian, that $P$ and $H$ commute, and thus since $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle P\rangle=[H,P]=0$.
The last part of the problem simply requests: "Express $P$ as a function of $H$."

I'm totally confused here. What does this even mean? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is a function and $A$ is an operator, then $f$ can be extended to $A$ (i.e. "we give meaning to $f(A)$") in two main ways:

- If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n$ has a suitably-regular Taylor series and $A$ is well-behaved enough, then we can define $$f(A) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n A^n.$$
- Otherwise, if $A = \sum_k a_k |k\rangle\langle k |$ has a suitable eigenvector diagonalization expansion, then we can define $$f(A) = \sum_k f(a_k) |k\rangle\langle k |.$$

Your set-piece is asking you to find a suitable function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ such that $f(H)=P$. A good place to start for this is thinking about the number operator, and what effect $P$ should have on its eigenstates.

Comment: Since the question is now closed, I've accepted your answer. But I'd also like to follow up a bit if possible: The Hermite polynomials in the eigenstates of the number operator tell that eigenstates alternate in parity, with the ground state being even. Thus in the even case ($|2k\rangle$), $P$ has no effect. In the odd case, there is a sign flip on wavefunction. Is $f$ going to be piecewise?